# Problema con la camara con opencv

Tags: python, opencv, hardware

Hola soy nuevo utilizando Opencv y no se si tengo algun problema con mi camara o es problema de mi codigo, intento ejecutar el siguiente codigo

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

while(True):
    #Captura frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read();

    #Muestra el resultado de frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#Cuando todo este hecho cierra el programa
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

me aparece la camara asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ademas no se me quiere apagar la camara cuando cierro la aplicacion.
Me gustaria vuestra ayuda para poder solucionar el problema

Answer (score 2):

Te diría que probases con otros números en:

> cv2.VideoCapture(0);

Pero si la cámara se prende es por que está iniciada

Prueba con un programa externo o la pagina webcamtoy para ver si se inicia la cámara y se ve bien así podrás descartar

Este código funciona por si dudas de tu código

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    _, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, al final el problema fue que descargue el opencv solamente en miniconda(creo), al descargar con el comando pip install opencv-python, me funciono correctamente

Comment: Yo uso el IDE por defecto o visual studio otras cosas las encuentro un enredo innecesario

Answer (score 0):

No olvides incluir la instrucción `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` para que se cierren las ventanas abiertas de `cv2.imshow()` luego de haber liberado la cámara.